# Put two window results to a window with two tabs

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

There are two buttons at the start page. The buttons show two different results. Popping two windows for viewing the results seemed too crowdy. I want the results to be displayed in a window with two tabs (two tabs refering to the two results from the buttoms) with a click of a single button in the first window. How can I do that?

The code below is executable.

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

all_figures1 = []
selected_figure1 = 0 
all_figures2 = []
selected_figure2 = 0 


class MyClass1():

    def __init__(self):

        self.sheets = [[1,2,3], [3,1,2], [1,5,1]]
        self.W = 2
        self.L = 5


    def plot_sheet(self, data):
        """plot single figure"""

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

        ax.set_xlim([0, self.W]) 
        ax.set_ylim([0, self.L])

        ax.plot(data)

        return fig

    def generate_all_figures(self):
        """create all figures and keep them on list"""
        global all_figures

        for data in self.sheets:
            fig = self.plot_sheet(data)
            all_figures1.append(fig)


class MyClass2():

    def __init__(self):

        self.sheets = [[3,2,1], [2,5,3], [5,1,5]]
        self.W = 2
        self.L = 5


    def plot_sheet(self, data):
        """plot single figure"""

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

        ax.set_xlim([0, self.W]) 
        ax.set_ylim([0, self.L])

        ax.plot(data)

        return fig

    def generate_all_figures(self):
        """create all figures and keep them on list"""
        global all_figures

        for data in self.sheets:
            fig = self.plot_sheet(data)
            all_figures2.append(fig)


dataPlot1 = None  
dataPlot2 = None  

def on_window1():

    def show_figure(number):
        global dataPlot1

        current_num = str(number+1)
        total_num = str(len(all_figures1))



        counter = tk.Label(top, text = current_num + "/" + total_num)
        counter.grid(row=4,column=0)



        # remove old canvas
        if dataPlot1 is not None: # at start there is no canvas to destroy
            dataPlot1.get_tk_widget().destroy()

        # get figure from list
        one_figure = all_figures1[number]

        # display canvas with figuere
        dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(one_figure, master=top)
        dataPlot.draw()
        dataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

        toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(top)
        toolbar_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(dataPlot, toolbar_frame)
        toolbar.update()

    def on_prev():
        global selected_figure1

        # get number of previous figure
        selected_figure1 -= 1
        if selected_figure1 < 0:
            selected_figure1 = len(all_figures1)-1

        show_figure(selected_figure1)

    def on_next():
        global selected_figure1

        # get number of next figure
        selected_figure1 += 1
        if selected_figure1 > len(all_figures1)-1:
            selected_figure1 = 0

        show_figure(selected_figure1)

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.wm_geometry("794x370")
    top.title('Optimized Map 1')

    selected_figure1 = 0
    dataPlot = None # default value for `show_figure`
    show_figure(selected_figure1)

    frame = tk.Frame(top)
    frame.grid(row=3, column=0)

    b1 = tk.Button(frame, text="<<", command=on_prev)
    b1.grid(row=2, column=0)

    b2 = tk.Button(frame, text=">>", command=on_next)
    b2.grid(row=2, column=1)



def on_window2():

    def show_figure(number):
        global dataPlot2

        current_num = str(number+1)
        total_num = str(len(all_figures2))


        counter = tk.Label(top, text = current_num + "/" + total_num)
        counter.grid(row=4,column=0)



        # remove old canvas
        if dataPlot2 is not None: # at start there is no canvas to destroy
            dataPlot2.get_tk_widget().destroy()

        # get figure from list
        one_figure = all_figures2[number]

        # display canvas with figuere
        dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(one_figure, master=top)
        dataPlot.draw()
        dataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

        toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(top)
        toolbar_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(dataPlot, toolbar_frame)
        toolbar.update()

    def on_prev():
        global selected_figure2

        # get number of previous figure
        selected_figure2 -= 1
        if selected_figure2 < 0:
            selected_figure2 = len(all_figures2)-1

        show_figure(selected_figure2)

    def on_next():
        global selected_figure2

        # get number of next figure
        selected_figure2 += 1
        if selected_figure2 > len(all_figures2)-1:
            selected_figure2 = 0

        show_figure(selected_figure2)

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.wm_geometry("794x370")
    top.title('Optimized Map2')

    selected_figure2 = 0
    dataPlot = None # default value for `show_figure`
    show_figure(selected_figure2)

    frame = tk.Frame(top)
    frame.grid(row=3, column=0)

    b1 = tk.Button(frame, text="<<", command=on_prev)
    b1.grid(row=2, column=0)

    b2 = tk.Button(frame, text=">>", command=on_next)
    b2.grid(row=2, column=1)

window = tk.Tk()

mc1 = MyClass1()
mc1.generate_all_figures()

mc2 = MyClass2()
mc2.generate_all_figures()

b1 = tk.Button(window, text="Next", command=on_window1)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

b2 = tk.Button(window, text="Next", command=on_window2)
b2.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a function along the lines of something like:

```
def switch_tabs(clicked):
    global active
    tabs[active].grid_forget()
    tabs[clicked].grid()
    active = clicked
```

where `tabs` could be a list or dict of keys to frames, `active` is a global variable representing the active tab, and `clicked` is a key that represents the tab that was clicked. The frames themselves would need a common parent - like the main window. [Here's some documentation](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_forget-method) on `grid_forget`.

Then when you create your buttons, you could wrap this function in a lambda that points directly to its tab. You'd probably want to put the button itself on the same frame as the common parent of the two tabs.

```
b1 = tk.Button(window, text="<<", command=lambda: switch_tabs(tab1))
```

In this case `tab1` could be a string or integer which associates to the tab you want to switch to by pressing the button. For instance, `tab1` might be `0` if you're using a list to store the frames - or it might be `'tab1'` if you're using a dict.

Here, I also used a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) as a quick and simple way to define a new function. I could just has easily written something like

```
def switch_to_tab1():
    switch_tabs(tab1)
b1 = tk.Button(window, text="<<", command=switch_to_tab1)
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out the b1 part. Could you explain.

Comment: @devinxxxd I've edited my answer to hopefully provide more clarity.